# Lodash equivalent of hoek.reach (hapijs)?

Tags: javascript, lodash, hapi.js

Hoek.reach solves an interesting and age-old problem of javascript object traversing: https://github.com/hapijs/hoek#reachobj-chain-options.

Example:

```
var chain = 'a.b.c';
var obj = {a : {b : { c : 1}}};

Hoek.reach(obj, chain); // returns 1
```

I want just this functionality of Hoek and nothing else. Just wondering if this functionality is in Lodash? I scanned through lodash doc quickly but it doesn't seem to be there.

Trying to figure out if I have a way to do this without adding "hoek" as my dep. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why do you think this question is bad? I'd appreciate comments with the problems in my question so that I can improve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using the npm module [property-path](https://www.npmjs.com/package/property-path) then adding it as a lodash mixin like so

```
var propPath = require('property-path')
  , _ = require('lodash')
  , obj = {a : {b : { c : 1}}}
  , chain = 'a.b.c'

_.mixin({ 'reach': propPath.get })

_.reach(obj, chain)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`_.get()`](https://lodash.com/docs#get):

```
var _ = require('lodash');

var chain = 'a.b.c';
var obj = {a : {b : { c : 1}}};

var result = _.get(obj, chain);
```